# How to solve this recursion relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, induction

Suppose:
$$2k(n-k)a_k=n(n-1)+(n-k)(k+1)a_{k+1}+(n-k)(k-1)a_{k-1}$$

where $k=1, 2, ..., n-1$ and $a_n=0$,

how to derive $a_k$?

I tried to find pattern $a_1-a_2=n/2$; $a_2-a3=n(2n-1)/6(n-2)$, it become more and more complicated and I can't find the rule.

Comment: Since your recursive relation includes $a_{k-1}, a_k, a_{k+1}$, you would need to specify one more initial condition. Or do you assume it to be some arbitrary constant?

Comment: @HarisGusic you can take a0 to be anything, cause it wont affect the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can finish Cesareo’s [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3116513/71850) as follows. For each $1\le k\le n$ we have $c_k=c_{n}+n(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac 1i$. Then for each $1\le l\le n$,

$$b_{l-1}=-\sum_{k=l}^n c_k=-\sum_{k=l}^n c_{n}+n(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac 1i=$$
$$- (n-l+1)c_n- n(n+1)\sum_{k=l}^n\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac 1i=$$
$$- (n-l+1)c_n- n(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n-l}\frac{n-i-l+1}i=$$
$$- (n-l+1)c_n- n(n+1)\left(l-n+(n-l+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n-l}\frac{1}i\right).$$

Remark that

$$0=b_0=- nc_n- n(n+1)\left(1-n+n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}i\right).$$

We assume that $n\ge 1$. Then

$$c_n=-(n+1)\left(1-n+n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}i\right),$$

so  for $2\le l\le n,$

$$a_{l-1}=\frac {b_{l-1}}{l-1}=\frac{n+1}{l-1}\left((n-l+1)\left(1-n+n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}i\right)-n\left(l-n+(n-l+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n-l}\frac{1}i\right)\right)=$$
$$\frac{n+1}{l-1}\left(1-l+n(n-l+1) \sum_{i=n-l+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}i \right).$$

Finally, for $1\le k\le n-1,$

$$a_{k}=\frac{n+1}{k}\left(-k+n(n-k) \sum_{i=n-k}^{n-1}\frac{1}i \right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Making $b_k = k a_k$ we have

$$
-b_{k-1}+2 b_k - b_{k+1} = \frac{n(n+1)}{n-k}
$$

This can be simplified by making $c_k = b_k-b_{k-1}$ giving

$$
c_k-c_{k+1} = \frac{n(n+1)}{n-k}
$$

After solving for $c_k$ can be then solved for $b_k$

Comment: I cant carry on with this hint

Comment: @buzhidao Please. See note attached.

Comment: No boundary condition for c0 or cn

Comment: @buzhidao To solve this recursion we need two boundary conditions. One is $a_n = b_n = 0$ so $c_n = -b_{n-1}$

Comment: However you dont know b_n-1

Comment: @buzhidao Try to solve it.

Comment: I can get to $c_1-c_n=n(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$, then what to do?